# Why does xslt stop producing when it encounters &amp;

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to convert an xml document with xslt.  My xml contains properly formatted ampersands.  My output stops as soon as there is one in my xml.  I have recreated it with w3schools example. Here is the link:
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_ex3
And a screenshot:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t8tv.png)
If I change one line by adding a formatted ampersand, it will stop producing results.
I changed this line in the xml:
Bob Dylan
To this line:
Bob & Dylan
Then it stops producing results at that line.
Screenshot:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjtLg.png)

Can someone please tell me why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: If you use  `&amp;amp;` it seems to work...Normally `&amp;` should work inside normal xml. But here you are editing inside a texterea

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] as code within your question, not as pictures in external links. Here you can see that there is no problem processing a properly escaped ampersand: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94humrB. I would not trust the w3schools test tool.

Comment: Thank you @michael.hor257k for the suggestions on how to create better questions. :)  I will be switching to the suggested tool below.  Not real sure how I mark this question done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with your code or XML but rather a limitation of the editing widget and supporting code used by W3Schools.

You can workaround the issue by replacing

```
<artist>Bob &amp; Dylan</artist>
```

(which really should work) with

```
<artist>Bob &amp;amp; Dylan</artist>
```

as a sort of double escape for just the purposes of seeing your code work in their limited editor.

---

**Update** <sub><sup>Thanks, [@michael.hor257k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016153/michael-hor257k)</sup></sub>:

[Martin Honnen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252228/martin-honnen) has a reliable site for testing XSLT online: [.NET XSLT Fiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/)

(Note that it's not limited to testing .NET-based XSLT.)

Comment: Even better, find a more capable testing environment.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Yes, a reliable dev/test environment such as [Martin's .NET XSLT Fiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/) is absolutely better than working around this problem and likely and endless series of problems yet to be discovered in a bad tool.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: IIRC, a series of other problems have already been discovered and reported here.

Comment: Thank you all for the help!!  I also really appreciate the suggestions for a different testing environment - have been trying to find another one that doesn't look like a scam for a few days!

Comment: @JessicaMaistrovich, there is also the pure browser side https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/ which also exists as a progressive web application (PWA) you can install locally: https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddlePWA/. (Disclaimer: I am the author of these tools but they are certainly meant to allow you to experiment with XSLT (3), not any scam.)

Comment: @MartinHonnen is being open (and modest) in his disclaimer.  That he is the author of these tools lend credibility, not concern, as his XSLT knowledge, skills, and contribution to the community are world class.